# How to use a variable from .ts file in .js file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, build

I have an environment.ts file

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  test: false
};
```

and concat.js file:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const concat = require('concat');
//const env  = require('src/environments/environment').environment;
```

and build script:

```
npm run build && node concat.js
```

if I using this code `const env  = require('src/environments/environment').environment;`

I have an error:

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'src/environments/environment'
```

How can I use the 'environment' variable (define in environment.ts file) in the concat.js file?

Comment: you either need to compile the TS to JS before or make your script a TS file as well, you can include JS in TS but not vice-versa

Comment: try require('./src/environments/environment').environment

Comment: @SerhiiBilyk it's still not working :(